# Is there a suitable map framework I can use to build this simple map app?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, geolocation, maps

I've seen a number of similar topics posted but I wanted to be more specific as I can't determine from the other posts which solution would work best for me.

**App details**

I would like to create a simple map application showing a town centre (for commercial use. I would like to avoid any map-licensing issues).

I envisage that all of the information would be drawn directly on to a single map image, which would be a png file (I'm not sure how such a large image would look when zoomed out - so if anyone has experience in this and can advise me whether I would need to tile the map and have a series of zoomed images I would appreciate it.)

**What I probably don't need**

I don't think I require tiling of images (see above), and I don't require pins, popups or route-planning (popups would be nice but not necessary).

**What I would like**

I would however love it if the user could press a button and zoom in roughly on their current location. Most solutions I've read about sound too overblown for my needs.

Can anyone suggest a good framework or alternative way of approaching this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[MapKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html) is very easy to use and covers all of the points up there, except for custom drawing.

Comment: Thank you.

Apologies, by "I envisage that all of the information would be drawn directly on to a single map image, which would be a png file" I meant that I want to import a pre-made flat image file  - there will be no need for dynamic drawing at runtime.

@WolfLink Can I just clarify - you are saying that I would be able to use my own maps within Mapkit?

Comment: You cannot use a custom map instead of the default one, but you can add annotations and overlays.  It would probably be a lot easier and more efficient this way than with a large image.  If you want to stick with the large image, look at UIWebView.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying :] Yes, I understand a standard map may be easier but the custom map is key. I will take a look at UIWebView - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use open street map service (see this [link](http://cloudmade.com/)). You can create your custom map by [Tile Mill](http://mapbox.com/tilemill/) Application. If you need to dynamically add images over map, some more tricks are required.